# How to place my own object on map?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I am learning maps in iphopne i have read a tutorial and successfully added a pin to a specific location ....

How do I show my own picture at the place of the pin?

Please provide some code if possible...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"CameraAnnotation";
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinView == nil )
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
        UIImageView *pinImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 32)];
        UIImage *pinImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pinImage" ofType:@"png"]];
        pinImageView.image = pinImage;
        [pinImage release];         

        [pinView addSubview:pinImageView];
        [pinImageView release];

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

        UIButton* photoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        photoButton.tag = ((PinAnnotationView*)annotation).tag;
        pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = photoButton;
        return pinView;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i do not know is it my mistake or not but my program crashes at       photoButton.tag = ((PinAnnotationView*)annotation).tag;

Comment: OK i have commented that and now the it worked but problem is that i also showing pin and then my image over it(my image is small so back is visible)...

Comment: yaar me never use this before but i know it is working because i see its working and we upload this code to app store for chatting application

Comment: ((PinAnnotationView*)annotation).tag PinAnnotationView is the view for you annotation use that view name in place of that

Comment: +1----for your answer it is working....now i have some other problems can i ask them...do you have enough time...

Comment: yes sure if i know then i give you answer of and that happy to help you

Comment: hello you can ask any thing it will increase my knowladge